# How to put an external dependency in the bundle file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a node app. It uses Knex library, which has a dependency `pg-query-stream`. It expects to see it inside `node_modules` when running the app.

As I build the app with webpack, I want to see this depdendency in the bundle file with all the other code.

Is it possible to do and how?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-local-libs

Comment: Isn't it the default webpack behavior ?